# YA Horror Short Story Collection

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I hope you can help me remember the name of this book! I believe all of the stories were written by the same author, but I'm ready to be proven wrong.

In one, maybe the longest, a boy graffitis the Egypt exhibit at the (British?) museum. The museum curator is revealed to be Anubis in disguise, and mummifies the boy alive.

In another, a kid who is trying to prove he is badass is dared to stay in the cemetery overnight. He paints his face to scare his friends, but before they find him he is attacked by a vampire. He is saved by the vampire's mother, who chides the vampire on not gunking his teeth correctly and being too tidy (compared to the boy's mother who chides him for being too messy). At the end of the story his friends find him laughing and wiping his face, saying "they're just like us!"

In another, a girl feeds the lake behind her house a spoonful of honey each day to keep it happy. Eventually her abusive father intervenes and the lake takes him away.

In the last, a ghost of a peasant boy haunts his old estate. His only desire is to try a sugar stick, a delicacy the lord of the manor partook of but the peasants never got to try. He makes contact with a girl, who gives him a taste of her candy, which he hates. He's like I can't believe people eat this! I waited around for this?? And then his ghost is set free.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like *Seven Strange and Ghostly Tales* by Brian Jacques.  Just look at the description (from Goodreads):

> From a teenager who drives a museum curator to mummify him for signing Phantom Snake (an anagram of his name) all over his exhibits, to a boy who's dared to visit the tomb of a vampire at midnight only to discover that the vampire boy he meets has a mother who nags just like his own, the eerie and chilling settings and characters will captivate readers.

Also from a review on Goodreads:

> (...) a lad named Gilly meets a tragic accidental end one day as he begs for a piece of candy from one of the four daughters of the landowner for whom his father works. Sadly, Gilly's request for a sugar stick isn't granted by the daughter before he suffers his fatal accident (...)